# R: characters turned into NA after rbind'ing with an empty character data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, rbind, r-factor

so my question might be very basic. I appreciate any help though:

I am trying to parse a nested list into a data frame using loops. 
To do this, I first created an empty data frame, with column names and all columns as characters:

```
dat<-data.frame(a=character(0), b=character(0), c=character(0), d=character(0), e=character(0), f=character(0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Right now str(dat) would return something like this:

```
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  6 variables:

 $ a: chr 
 $ b : chr 
 $ c: chr 
 $ d: chr 
 $ e: chr 
 $ f: chr
```

Then using for loops, I was able to extract list of variables from the nested list. There are several nested loops dealing with several nested data frames, so here is the simplified version:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  a<-"sdfsaf"
  b<-"dfadasfsd"
  c<-"fdsfsadf"
  d<-"dfads"
  e<-"sfdsfdsf"
  f<-"dfsfsdf"
  dat<-rbind(dat,setNames(as.list(c(a,b,c,d,e,f)),names(dat)))    
}
```

After the first loop (i==1), the returned dat will look like this:

```
     a            b            c            d          e            f
2  sdfsaf      dfadasfsd    fdsfsadf        dfads     sfdsfdsf      dfsfsdf
```

Everything looks good. However, after all three loops completed, what I got is like this:

```
 a            b            c            d          e            f
2  sdfsaf      dfadasfsd    fdsfsadf        dfads     sfdsfdsf      dfsfsdf
3 <NA>        <NA>       <NA>             <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
4  <NA>        <NA>       <NA>              <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
```

Now I checked str(dat). The columns in the data frame changed into factors! It shows something like this:
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:

```
 $ a: Factor w/ 1 level "sdfsaf": 1 NA NA 
 $ b : Factor w/ 1 level "dfadasfsd": 1 NA NA
 $ c: Factor w/ 1 level "fdsfsadf": 1 NA NA
 $ d: Factor w/ 1 level "dfads": 1 NA NA
 $ e: Factor w/ 1 level "sfdsfdsf": 1 NA NA
 $ f: Factor w/ 1 level "dfsfsdf": 1 NA NA
```

I used source to debug and made sure that each variable in each loop was not NA or NULL. I also used class() to make sure each variable is character type - how could a vector of characters combine with an character type data frame would change everything into factors?

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: `data.frame` converts characters to factors unless you have `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`; I assume it's getting called when you `rbind` a list to a data.frame. Building a data.frame with a `for` loop is really inadvisable, though; what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks! I know that I probably should have used tapply or lapply or apply, but `for` loop is just easier to wrap my head around this nested list/json file. Basically the data I want are from a 16 column data frame, with one of the column being a nested list with three levels. Also, the number of elements of that list varies for every row of the data. But now using the method @Arun kumar mahesh , I got this problem solved. I need to come back later to find a more efficient way to do this. But for now I am running out of time. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, turned out your advice was right: "Building a data.frame with a for loop is really inadvisable, though." The `dat[,1:6] <-apply(dat[,1:6],2, as.character)` approach first seemed to work. Then I got this error message: `Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` after several loops. I assume the `apply` function calls `if`? Otherwise why would this error show up right after `dat[,1:6] <-apply(dat[,1:6],2, as.character)`? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:3){
  dat<-rbind(dat,setNames(as.list(c(a,b,c,d,e,f)),names(dat)))

}

dat[,1:6] <-apply(dat[,1:6],2, as.character)

str(dat)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
  $ a: chr  "sdfsaf" "sdfsaf" "sdfsaf"
$ b: chr  "dfadasfsd" "dfadasfsd" "dfadasfsd"
$ c: chr  "fdsfsadf" "fdsfsadf" "fdsfsadf"
$ d: chr  "dfads" "dfads" "dfads"
$ e: chr  "sfdsfdsf" "sfdsfdsf" "sfdsfdsf"
$ f: chr  "dfsfsdf" "dfsfsdf" "dfsfsdf"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried this method and worked as a charm! Now I have all my character vectors added into the empty data frame!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `rbind` line with:

```
dat <- rbind(dat, setNames(as.list(c(a,b,c,d,e,f)), names(dat)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is the complete script without output:

```
> dat<-data.frame(a=character(0), b=character(0), c=character(0), d=character(0), e=character(0), f=character(0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> for(i in 1:3){
+   a<-"sdfsaf"
+   b<-"dfadasfsd"
+   c<-"fdsfsadf"
+   d<-"dfads"
+   e<-"sfdsfdsf"
+   f<-"dfsfsdf"
+   dat<-rbind(dat,setNames(as.list(c(a,b,c,d,e,f)),names(dat)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
+ }
> dat
       a         b        c     d        e       f
1 sdfsaf dfadasfsd fdsfsadf dfads sfdsfdsf dfsfsdf
2 sdfsaf dfadasfsd fdsfsadf dfads sfdsfdsf dfsfsdf
3 sdfsaf dfadasfsd fdsfsadf dfads sfdsfdsf dfsfsdf
```

I got this answer both under R 3.3.1 and the development version of R.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, but got something like this:

Comment: post_id author subject content  type  when
2                  post_id author subject content  type  when
stringsAsFactors     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
3                     <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
stringsAsFactors1    FALSE  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
5                     <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>

Comment: I have shown the complete script with output and as you can see it gives the expected answer.

Comment: I copied and ran your complete script in my Rconsole and here is what I got:

Comment: for(i in 1:3){
+     a<-"sdfsaf"
+     b<-"dfadasfsd"
+     c<-"fdsfsadf"
+     d<-"dfads"
+     e<-"sfdsfdsf"
+     f<-"dfsfsdf"
+     dat<-rbind(dat,setNames(as.list(c(a,b,c,d,e,f)),names(dat)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
+ }
debug at #2: a <- "sdfsaf"
Browse[4]> dat
[1] a b c d e f
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: If that is the complete code then you didn't re-initiatize dat.  Suggest you exit R, start it up again and do it all from the beginning.  Also make sure you are not using an old version of R.  My code was run under R 3.3.1 and the development verison of R and both gave the expected answer.